# Using QBXML to create a vendor, and the documentation seems wrong

Tags: qbxml, qbwc

I'm using Quickbooks Web Connector and qbxml to add vendors, bills, and payments to QB.  The basic code works fine and adds the vendors, bills, and payments.

The problem that I'm having is that some of the fields seem to be misnamed in xml, specifically IsVendorEligibleFor1099, VendorTaxIdent, IsActive, and a few others that I don't care as much about.

This chunk of code works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <?qbxml version="' . $version . '"?>
  <QBXML>
     <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <VendorAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
           <VendorAdd>
              <Name>' .  substr($arr['company_name'],0,39) . '</Name>
              <CompanyName>' . substr($arr['company_name'],0,39) . '</CompanyName>
              <VendorAddress>
                 <Addr1>' . substr($arr['address'],0,39) . '</Addr1>                     
                 <Country >' . substr($arr['country'],0,29) . '</Country>
              </VendorAddress>
              <Phone>' . substr($arr['phone'],0,19) . '</Phone> 
              <Email>' . $arr['email'] . '</Email> 
              <Contact>' . substr($arr['contact_name'],0,39) . '</Contact>
              <AccountNumber>Payee '. $arr['payee_id'] .'</AccountNumber>
              <Notes>this is a note!</Notes>
           </VendorAdd>
        </VendorAddRq>
     </QBXMLMsgsRq>
  </QBXML>
```

(sorry about the ugly there)

If I add `<IsVendorEligibleFor1099>True</IsVendorEligibleFor1099>` QB errors out on import.

Any ideas?  (I already know that the various $arr[] items need to be escaped, but that's not the problem here)

Comment: Make sure you have the order correct. Post the XML that is being generated that is failing.

Comment: Imagine the above with the "IsVendor..." right above or below "Notes".  The order really shouldn't matter, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently order *does* matter, among other things. Adding:

```
<IsVendorEligibleFor1099>%s</IsVendorEligibleFor1099>
```

Right after the Notes line seems to work, not sure what was causing issues before.  It's very picky about the order.